# link_to in Rails 7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am new to Ruby on Rails and I am making a view page showing a table from the database. I want to add a link_to to delete this record. I tried the code written below and nothing worked for me.

The browser keeps refreshing and does nothing.

ruby 3.1.2
Rails 7.0.4

```
<%= link_to 'Delete', @friend, data: {turbo_method: :delete, turbo_confirm: 'Sure?'}, class: "btn btn-danger" %>
```

also with this

```
<%= link_to 'Delete', @friend, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }, class: "btn btn-danger" %>
```

**html.erb code**

```html
<p style="color: green"><%= notice %></p>

<%= render @friend %>

<div>
  <%= link_to "Edit this friend", edit_friend_path(@friend) %> |
  <%= link_to "Back to friends", friends_path %>

  <%#= button_to "Destroy this friend", @friend, method: :delete,data: {turbo_confirm: 'Are you sure?'} %>
  <%#= button_to "Destroy this friend", @friend, method: :delete,data: {turbo_confirm: 'Are you sure?'} %>
  <%= link_to 'Delete', @friend, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }, class: "btn btn-danger" %>
</div>
```

**Controller code**

```
class FriendsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_friend, only: %i[ show edit update destroy ]

  # GET /friends or /friends.json
  def index
    @friends = Friend.all
  end

  # GET /friends/1 or /friends/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /friends/new
  def new
    @friend = Friend.new
  end

  # GET /friends/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /friends or /friends.json
  def create
    @friend = Friend.new(friend_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @friend.save
        format.html { redirect_to friend_url(@friend), notice: "Friend was successfully created." }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @friend }
      else
        format.html { render :new, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        format.json { render json: @friend.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /friends/1 or /friends/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @friend.update(friend_params)
        format.html { redirect_to friend_url(@friend), notice: "Friend was successfully updated." }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @friend }
      else
        format.html { render :edit, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        format.json { render json: @friend.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /friends/1 or /friends/1.json
  def destroy
    @friend.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to friends_url, notice: "Friend was successfully destroyed." }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_friend
      @friend = Friend.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Only allow a list of trusted parameters through.
    def friend_params
      params.require(:friend).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :phone, :twitter)
    end
end
```

Comment: Can you please paste the html generated by your above code. Also your controller destroy action pls.

Comment: @Maxence post edited

Comment: `method: :delete` is used by the old Rails UJS driver. For Turbo you need`data: { turblinks_method: :delete }`. If it still is just sent as a normal GET request you need do some troubleshooting and see that Turbo is present on the page and that you don't have any JavaScript errors that are preventing it from working. https://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#method

Answer (score 1):

Your code should work

```
<%= link_to 'Delete', @friend,
  data: {turbo_method: :delete, turbo_confirm: 'Sure?'}, class: "btn btn-danger" %>
```

But more reliable to use `button_to` that generate `form` tag with button

```
<%= button_to 'Delete', @friend,
  method: :delete, form: {data: {turbo_confirm: 'Sure?'}}, class: "btn btn-danger" %>
```

Comment: Agreed, use button_to. I believe there is a PR in turbo where you can attach a method as well, while still using link_to, but am not 100% sure on this.

Comment: @mechnicov
the button worked but without confirmation

Comment: @MohamedMedhat it means turbo is not working on that page (or even in the project)